# Gradle bring a wrong version of a transitive dependency[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Gradle]

Tags: gradle, dependencies, classnotfoundexception

I have a multi-project build.

One of its modules X brings a dependency B that contains the transitive elastic client dependency:

```
    api (group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: 7.9.0) {
        exclude group: 'org.yaml', module: 'snakeyaml'
    }
```

I have the tests inside X that use methods of B where I pass elastic client classes as arguments.

X uses Spring Boot Gradle plugin.

In the runtime, during the execution of integration tests that use dependency B for ES testing, I get this exception(original classes are masked)

```
Exception in thread "I/O dispatcher 4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/AliasMetadata
        at dependencyB.myESService.index
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap$MapSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleMap.java:57)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess$DoOnSuccess.onSuccess(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:60)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleResumeNext$ResumeMainSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleResumeNext.java:65)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback$FlatMapSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:111)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.onSuccess(SingleCreate.java:67)
...
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient$1.onSuccess(RestHighLevelClient.java:1663)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onSuccess(RestClient.java:590)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:333)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:327)
        at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetadata
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 27 more
```

I don't use the conflicting class directly.

Gradle task  *dependencies* gave me a hint(masked internal versions and names)

```
+--- org.path:dependencyB:123
|    +--- org.path:another-lib:123 (*)
|    +--- org.path:third-lib:123 (*)
|    \--- **org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.9.0 -> 7.6.2**
```

As I understand the version `7.6.2` of the ES client is being used instead of the `7.9.0` and that causes the issue.

I have no idea why does it happen - ES client is not being pulled from anywhere else as far as I am concerned and [there are no custom rules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html) for the dependency versions.

Am I correct and how to fix it? Any hints? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the [Spring Dependency Management plugin](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/)?

Comment: Yes............
        
classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE
classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.11.RELEASE'

Comment: Maybe full dependency tree is needed.